# terraform Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to pass the endpoint_id value to an ssm parameter but getting the following error:

> │   on main.tf line 40, in resource "aws_ssm_parameter"
> "the_cloud_ngfw_endpoint": ::error::Terraform exited with code 1. │
> 40:   value =
> cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[*].status[0].attachment[0].endpoint_id
> │     ├──────────────── │     │ cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw is
> tuple with 2 elements │  │ Inappropriate value for attribute "value":
> string required.

my code:

```
resource "cloudngfwaws_ngfw" "the_cloud_ngfw" {
  count  = length(local.subnet_id_list)
  name        = "${var.projectname}-cloudngfw1-${local.account_id}-${local.az_list[count.index]}-${count.index}"
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
  account_id  = local.account_id
  description = "NGFW resource for Project ${var.projectname}"
  endpoint_mode = "ServiceManaged"
  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = local.subnet_id_list[count.index]
  }
  rulestack = "${var.env_name}-${var.rule_stack_name}"
  tags = {
    project = var.projectname
  }
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "the_cloud_ngfw_endpoint" {
  count  = length(local.subnet_id_list)
  name  = "/test/endpoint${count.index}"
  type  = "String"
  value = cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[*].status[0].attachment[0].endpoint_id
}
```

Comment: You cannot use more than one string for the `value` argument.

Comment: i tried accessing with value = cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[count.index].status[0].attachment[0].endpoint_id but i'm getting error as well, how can access it properly?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to one of your previous questions, I don't know what the output of `cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw` is, so I cannot really give an answer.

Comment: You are using splat expression and it's returning 2 endpoints. Try with `cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[${count.index}].status[0].attachment[0].endpoint_id`